# How to mock an object and verify a given parameter was provided to this mock

Tags: angular, unit-testing, testing, mocking, ng-mocks

I'm trying to test an `HttpInterceptor`, with the help of `ng-mocks`:

```js
    @Injectable()
    export class AuthTokenInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
      constructor(private store: Store) {}
    
      intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        const currentToken = this.store.selectSnapshot(state => state.accounts.accessToken);
    
        if (currentToken) {
          req = req.clone({
            setHeaders: { Authorization: `Bearer ${currentToken}` },
          });
        }
        return next.handle(req);
      }
    }
```

I'm having trouble to see how I could provide the `next` parameter, especially since I want to check that the object has the setHeaders property present(or not):

```js
    describe('Unauth guard test', () => {
      beforeEach(() => {
        return MockBuilder(AuthTokenInterceptor, AppModule).mock(Store);
      });
    
      it('should allow access if not authenticated', () => {
        //Arrange
        const fakeToken = 'fakeToken';
        const storeDispatchSpy = MockInstance(Store, 'selectSnapshot', jasmine.createSpy().and.returnValue(fakeToken));
        const httpHandlerSpy = MockInstance(HttpHandler, 'handle', jasmine.createSpy().and.returnValue(fakeToken));
        const fixture = MockRender(AuthTokenInterceptor);
        const interceptor = fixture.point.componentInstance;
       const request = new HttpRequest('GET', 'http://localhost:4200/');
    
        //Act
        const result = interceptor.intercept(request, httpHandlerSpy.???);//How to provide a mock of HttpHandler?
    
        //Assert
        expect(storeDispatchSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
        expect(httpHandlerSpy).toHaveBeenCalledOnceWith(???);//How to verify that one parameter of the HttpRequest is set to specific value?
      });
    });
```

But how to provide a mocked instance to the intercept method? and more complex, how to check that my spy have been called with an object that has a specific value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, you need to provide `mockStore` + isolate your interceptor from other interceptors.

An example from [`ng-mocks` docs and http interceptors](https://ng-mocks.sudo.eu/guides/http-interceptor).

https://codesandbox.io/s/intelligent-stallman-9bwup0?file=/src/test.spec.ts

```js
describe('AuthTokenInterceptor', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    return (
      MockBuilder(AuthTokenInterceptor, AppModule)
        // required for interceptors
        .exclude(NG_MOCKS_INTERCEPTORS)
        .keep(HTTP_INTERCEPTORS)

        .replace(HttpClientModule, HttpClientTestingModule)
    );
  });

  it('adds header', () => {
    // creating an empty fixture
    const fixture = MockRender('', null, false);

    // stubbing store
    const store = ngMocks.findInstance(Store);
    ngMocks.stubMember(store, 'selectSnapshot', callback =>
      callback({
        accounts: {
          accessToken: 'Testing',
        },
      }),
    );

    // render
    fixture.detectChanges();

    // instances to test how HttpClient uses interceptors
    const client = ngMocks.findInstance(HttpClient);
    const httpMock = ngMocks.findInstance(HttpTestingController);

    // Let's do a simple request.
    client.get('/target').subscribe();

    // Now we can assert that a header has been added to the request.
    const req = httpMock.expectOne('/target');
    req.flush('');
    httpMock.verify();

    // asserting headers
    expect(req.request.headers.get('Authorization')).toEqual(
      'Bearer Testing',
    );
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I still don't see how I can assert that my header has properly been added? Also, by testing this through the HttpClient, aren't we testing too much things in one Unit Test?

Comment: By the way, I'm not sure what is the equivalent of provideMockStore in NGXS

Comment: headers can be checked on `req`. Regarding `NGXS` - it's a good question. I've updated my example how to mock it, not sure if they have testing features like `NGRX`.

Comment: Thanks, I get a `This expression is not callable.` on the callback(..). Also, do you know the difference between fixture.debugElement.injector, ngMocks.findInstance and MockInstance?

Comment: do you use the latest version of `ng-mocks`? there is an example of the test: https://codesandbox.io/s/intelligent-stallman-9bwup0?file=/src/test.spec.ts

Comment: I was having a minor version late, I just updated but still get the same warning: `(parameter) callback: string | Type<any> | ((state: any, ...states: any[]) => T) | StateToken<T>
This expression is not callable.
  Not all constituents of type 'string | Type<any> | ((state: any, ...states: any[]) => T) | StateToken<T>' are callable.
    Type 'string' has no call signatures.ts(2349)`

Comment: what are the versions of typescript and ngsx?

Comment: try to cast it to `any` for now.

Comment: maybe your tsconfig is too strict and it requires to define types on the callback in `stubMember`.

Comment: It does work with any, and you're right, I've `strict:true` in my config file. Now the test seems to work. I was also able to remove the `fixture.detectChanges();`. I never explored the ngMocks.* domain, I definitely have to check this.

Comment: Great! Unfortunately, if a method has too many overrides, it’s hard to mock just one of them and to keep types safe. Because TS will complain that other overrides aren’t covered, although they aren’t needed in the current test